# Show array element on button click using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an array of strings, you can see below and i want to alert each element one by one on button click:

```
 function mysimplefunc() {
            var i = 0;
            var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
            if (array.length < 4)
            {
                var str = array[i];
                i++;
                alert(str);
            }
        }
```

below is asp code:

```
  <asp:Button ID="btn_SHow" runat="server" Text="Show Elements" OnClientClick="mysimplefunc();" />
```

But its not working.

Comment: so what is the issue??

Comment: use a loop..this would show you only the 1st element in the array

Comment: the loop is not working since array.length is 4 and not less than 4 and more over it will show only first element

Comment: iJay: No it will show only the last element of the array

Comment: @khanalihass can u plz update your code ...so that we can talk with respect to that

Comment: @khanalihass : check out my answer..!! it will work..!!

Answer (score 0):

the `if loop` will not working since array length is 4

and u must use `for loop` inorder to iterate each element..!!

```
for ( i=0;i<array.length;i++)
                {
                    var str = array[i];

                    alert(str);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function. This handles creating the array counter (i) as a global variable, and any number of items can be included in the array, not just four.

```
function mysimplefunc() {
     var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
     if (typeof i == "undefined") {i = 0};
                alert(array[i++]);
     if (i == array.length) {i = 0}
}
```

Comment: but It alert only "a" not all elements of array

Answer (score -1):

```
function mysimplefunc() {
            var i = 0;  //declare & initialise a integer variable used for loop counter. 
            var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]; //Create an string array of 4 elements with name array
            var arrLength=array.length; //find the length of array elements
            for (;i<arrLength;) //iterate over the array elements upto last element
            {
                var str = array[i]; //take first element from array 
                i++; //increment the loop counter
                alert(str);//popup the small window with values present in array
            }
        }
```

Comment: this wont alert all elements in the array as the OP wants

Comment: code looks fine...would be helpful if u explain your code before simply dump the code

Comment: It works fine but i want that when i click on show button at first time it alert("a"), at second time on click show button it alert("b")  at third time on click show button it alert("c") and so on...